# JavaScript permission denied.  Not cross domain?

Tags: javascript, exception, cross-domain

I'm working on a web app that very rarely returns a JavaScript permission denied error when attempting to access document elements.  I'm well aware of cross-domain issues and I am actively pursuing them as a possible cause.  My question is: are there other possible causes for a permission denied exception?  Just want to make sure I'm looking in to all possible avenues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually it just occurs for cross domain calls, but IE does it for other things too.  For instance, some properties and objects in the IE dom are inaccessible like document.styleSheets.rules.

http://www.dannyg.com/ref/jsminifaq.html#q15

It has also been said that assigning too long of strings to an URL will throw it:

http://javascriptfixer.com/access-is-denied.php

You can also get the error when submitting a form with an input=file if the input's value wasn't properly selected.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;892442

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The strange thing about my particular case is that the app calls this particular function literally hundreds (if not thousands) of times before the error occurs.  Something is happening behind the scenes...  I'm just pulling my hair out trying to figure out what...